# WARNING:tensorflow:create_partitioned_variables is deprecated

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm getting this `WARNING`

> WARNING:tensorflow:create_partitioned_variables is deprecated.  Use tf.get_variable with a partitioner set, or tf.get_partitioned_variable_list, instead.

I'm not using the function `create_partitioned_variables`

I'm using `tensorflow.__version__ 0.9.0`

What is the most appropriate way to resolve this `WARNING`

If you have tensorflow installed along with pandas/numpy, you should be able to copy and paste this code.

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tempfile

np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(cat1=np.random.choice(('Yes', 'No'), (100,),),
                       val1=np.random.rand(100),
                       val2=np.random.rand(100),
                       val3=np.random.rand(100),
                       label=np.random.choice((0, 1), (100,))))

LABEL_COLUMN = "label"

trainBegin, trainEnd = 0, 80
testBegin, testEnd = 80, 100
df_train = df.iloc[trainBegin:trainEnd, :]
df_test = df.iloc[testBegin:testEnd, :]

CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['cat1']

def input_fn(df):
    # Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
    # the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
    continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                       for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
    # Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
    # to the values of that column stored in a tf.SparseTensor.
    categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
            indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
            values=df[k].values,
            shape=[df[k].size, 1])
                        for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}
    # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
    feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())
    # Converts the label column into a constant Tensor.
    label = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)
    # Returns the feature columns and the label.
    return feature_cols, label

def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_train)

def eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_test)

val1 = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("val1")
val2 = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("val2")
val3 = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("val3")

cat1 = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="cat1", keys=["Yes", "No"])

wide_columns = [val1, val2, val3, cat1]
```

`WARNINGS` come when I run:

```
model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=wide_columns, model_dir=model_dir)

m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)

results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

[image]

If I run this instead:

```
model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=wide_columns[:-1], model_dir=model_dir)
# removing last feature columns which is categorical using [:-1]  ^^^^^

m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)

results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

I get no errors.

```
accuracy: 0.45
eval_auc: 0.459596
loss: 0.771354
```

#### Conclusion

I narrowed it down to using categorical features created using `.sparse_column_with_keys` but what am I supposed to do about it?

Comment: I do not use `.sparse_column_with_keys`, but I do use `.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket` and get the same warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `sparse_column_with_keys` is using `create_partitioned_variables()` for its initialization, however, within the `create_partitioned_variables()` class, they throw a warning that is basically saying that `create_partitioned_variables()` is not the accepted way of creating partitioned variables anymore. Instead, you can use the `get_variable()` function.

If you go to `tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers`, and open _feature_column.py_, you will find that the embedding for `sparse_column_with_keys` uses `create_partitioned_variables()`. To fix this, import the `get_variable function` (`from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope import get_variable`), and then define the variable `embeddings` (which should be using `create_partitioned_variables()` initially) using `get_variable()` instead of `create_partitioned_variables()`. I don't think the warning really matters much though.